# Embed weather forecast in email

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, ampscript

Short background: working for an international language school. I wish to set up an automation for people who have booked a course and the course is coming up soon (for ex next week). In that email I would like to mention the local weather for them to be able to prepare.

Now it's possible to pull an RSS feed into emails so I am guessing it could be possible to pull weather forecast information into an email automatically also. I'm guessing with heavy AMPscript usage.

Has anyone done anything like that before? Can you share it how you did it?

Comment: Have you seen the example on RSS feeds in emails? http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/

Comment: What weather feed are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the RSS feed link.
So far I haven't found any good weather feeds I could be using. Any ideas for that guys?

Comment: There are tons of them - a google search should come up with several.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code from the [documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/) showing how this can be accomplished.

```
%%[Var @xml, @titles, @title, @descs, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSParse\RSSParse") /* This line specifies the content area from which the RSS content will be pulled for the email message. */
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)

If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
  SET @rows = 5
ELSE
  SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
 for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
   Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
   Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
   Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%%

<div style="border: 1px solid #444; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 0.76em 0; padding: 0.76em;">
<h1 style="font: bold normal 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%% style="color: #000;">%%=v(@title)=%%</a></h1>
<span style="font: normal normal 0.76em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444;">%%=v(@desc)=%%</span>
</div>
%%[ 
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%
```

You would need to adjust for the particular feed you are using and the HTML output you want.

`BuildRowSetFromXML()` is simply one method. You can also utilize the `TransformXML()` functionality which is [documented here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_to_perform_an_xsl_transformation/).

I prefer the second method, as it allows me to use XSLT's which I'm A) More comfortable with, and B)Have more controls.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. I think I'm getting a general idea of this process, though I haven't used AMPscript nearly as complicated as this.
The problem I see here is that the XML transformation needs an ET landing page. Thus is needs the Microsites feature to be enabled for our account, which we don't have right now.
I suppose it cannot be done without an ET landing page, correct?  (thanks for all the help you gave so far)

Comment: This totally works in email. I've done it plenty.  Give it a shot.