# Are there any 3rd party sources that provide a dynamic weather forecast I can embed in SFMC email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, widget

I'm looking for an easy and affordable way to embed a dynamic weather forecast in an email campaign. Can anyone recommend a service or is there a way to do it with ampscript?

Comment: Check here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33046/embed-weather-forecast-in-email

Answer (score 0):

We use LiveClicker for this as well as other interactive elements. Fairly cheap for all that you get. Assuming your marketing program is large enough, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found this [site](https://openweathermap.org/api) that seems to offer XML/JSON feeds, you can integrate these into your email via AmpScript. I'm sure there are many other weather feeds, too.  If you need help on integrating feeds, [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/can-ampscript-parse-json) is what I used to experiment when I was trying to pull in web feeds.  If you want to customize based on location, you'll need to use an API to send your location information, I haven't used that aspect yet.